# EXTJS ERROR in api.php inclusion file in script tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, mongodb, extjs

i'm using sencha Extjs 6.0.2 in the forntend and mongodb in the backend. But, whenever i try to add api.php file in index.html file using script tag, it throws some exception. In index.html i add the following code for api.php file inclusion.

```
<script  src="php/api.php"  type="text/javascript"  ></script>
```

the Error is

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <     api.php?_dc=1468481913442:1
```

the problem that i found during debugging is that api.php file is called as html type. As far as i know php file should call as a php type, but it doesn't. some times when i resend the file respone using firebug, it type turned into xml. How can i get rid of this problem?

And the error i found after inspecting is below:

[image]

Here is my api.php code

```
  <?php
 require('config.php');       
//header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
header("content-type: application/x-javascript"); 

$API = get_extdirect_api('api');

// convert API config to Ext Direct spec

$actions = array();
foreach($API as $aname=>&$a){
 $methods = array();
foreach($a['methods'] as $mname=>&$m){
     if (isset($m['len'])) {
        $md = array(
            'name'=>$mname,
            'len'=>$m['len']
        );
    } else {
        $md = array(
            'name'=>$mname,
            'params'=>$m['params']
        );
    }
    if(isset($m['formHandler']) && $m['formHandler']){
        $md['formHandler'] = true;
    }

    if (isset($m['metadata'])) {
        $md['metadata'] = $m['metadata'];
    }
    $methods[] = $md;
}
$actions[$aname] = $methods;
}

$cfg = array(
'url'=>'php/router.php',
'type'=>'remoting',
'actions'=>$actions
 );
 echo 'var Ext = Ext || {}; Ext.REMOTING_API = ';

 echo json_encode($cfg);
 echo ';';
// document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript";
 ?>
```

i try to send the api.php file type as JS file.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: It isn't called as HTML type, it is called as `"text/javascript"` (javascript code). The browser then gets a response and determines that the content of the response is HTML. If you include something via `script` tag, the content returned should be javascript. Please show us what you are doing inside api.php, and what content api.php contains when it is returned to the browser.

Comment: @Alexander i add the code sample. and the file type that was catch by firebug.

Comment: Please add the output you see in your browser's network tab. Maybe it's just that your PHP file isn't executed because your server is not configured correctly.

Comment: yes, you are right. browser just shows the php file. but, we know that php file never execute in the browser..  @Alexander

Answer (score 0):

I am too new to write comments so I'll just write here I'm not sure if it is helpful but: What are you using to process the php file?

I had a similar problem while using the web server that the sencha cmd provide. This is just a basic HTTP webserver and  doesn't support php so you get back the php code instead of the javascript that the php code is supposed to produce.