# ExtJS PHP/MySQL backend connector error

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, extjs

exactly the same problem than on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368129/extjs-error-in-api-php-inclusion-file-in-script-tag/50370841?noredirect=1#comment87757603_50370841)

follow carefully the documentation (official) 
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/guides/backend_connectors/direct/mysql_php.html

did not understand how to solve it

edit
[here is a screenshot of firefox console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyzxB.png)

api.php (the file where the error is)
(took from ext js documentation and sdk examples)

```
<?php
require('config.php');

header('Content-Type: text/javascript');

$API = get_extdirect_api('api');

# convert API config to Ext Direct spec
$actions = array();
foreach($API as $aname=>&$a){
    $methods = array();
    foreach($a['methods'] as $mname=>&$m){
        if (isset($m['len'])) {
            $md = array(
                'name'=>$mname,
                'len'=>$m['len']
            );
        } else {
            $md = array(
                'name'=>$mname,
                'params'=>$m['params']
            );
        }
        if(isset($m['formHandler']) && $m['formHandler']){
            $md['formHandler'] = true;
        }

        if (isset($m['metadata'])) {
            $md['metadata'] = $m['metadata'];
        }
        $methods[] = $md;
    }
    $actions[$aname] = $methods;
}

$cfg = array(
    'url'=>'data/direct/router.php',
    'type'=>'remoting',
    'actions'=>$actions
);

echo 'var Ext = Ext || {}; Ext.REMOTING_API = ';

echo json_encode($cfg);
echo ';';

?>
```

app.json edited part as asked in the tutorial i linked

```
"js": [
        {
            "path": "${framework.dir}/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js"
        },
        {
            "path": "php/api.php",
            "remote": true
        },
        {
            "path": "app.js",
            "bundle": true
        }
    ],
```

application.js

```
/**
 * The main application class. An instance of this class is created by app.js when it
 * calls Ext.application(). This is the ideal place to handle application launch and
 * initialization details.
 */
Ext.define('DirectApp.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    name: 'DirectApp',

    quickTips: false,
    platformConfig: {
        desktop: {
            quickTips: true
        }
    },

    launch: function () {
        Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(Ext.REMOTING_API);
    },

    onAppUpdate: function () {
        Ext.Msg.confirm('Application Update', 'This application has an update, reload?',
            function (choice) {
                if (choice === 'yes') {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=10, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>DirectApp</title>

    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Cmd to build your application -->

    <script id="microloader" data-app="70f32dd6-f700-4939-bc96-3af4f1c9798b" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

here is the router took from sdk examples as i say you can do it in the tutorial

```
<?php
require('config.php');

class BogusAction {
    public $action;
    public $method;
    public $data;
    public $tid;
}

$isForm = false;
$isUpload = false;

if(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)){
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
    $data = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
}else if(isset($_POST['extAction'])) { // form post
    $isForm = true;
    $isUpload = $_POST['extUpload'] == 'true';
    $data = new BogusAction();
    $data->action = $_POST['extAction'];
    $data->method = $_POST['extMethod'];
    $data->tid = isset($_POST['extTID']) ? $_POST['extTID'] : null; // not set for upload
    $data->data = array($_POST, $_FILES);
}else if (($data = file_get_contents('php://input')) !== '') {
    $data = json_decode($data);
}else{
    die('Invalid request.');
}

function doRpc($cdata){
    $API = get_extdirect_api('router');

    try {
        if(!isset($API[$cdata->action])){
            throw new Exception('Call to undefined action: ' . $cdata->action);
        }

        $action = $cdata->action;
        $a = $API[$action];

        doAroundCalls($a['before'], $cdata);

        $method = $cdata->method;
        $mdef = $a['methods'][$method];
        if(!$mdef){
            throw new Exception("Call to undefined method: $method on action $action");
        }
        doAroundCalls($mdef['before'], $cdata);

        $r = array(
            'type'=>'rpc',
            'tid'=>$cdata->tid,
            'action'=>$action,
            'method'=>$method
        );

        require_once("classes/$action.php");
        $o = new $action();
        if (isset($mdef['len'])) {
            $params = isset($cdata->data) && is_array($cdata->data) ? $cdata->data : array();
        } else {
            $params = array($cdata->data);
        }

        array_push($params, $cdata->metadata);

        $r['result'] = call_user_func_array(array($o, $method), $params);

        doAroundCalls($mdef['after'], $cdata, $r);
        doAroundCalls($a['after'], $cdata, $r);
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        $r['type'] = 'exception';
        $r['message'] = $e->getMessage();
        $r['where'] = $e->getTraceAsString();
    }
    return $r;
}


function doAroundCalls(&$fns, &$cdata, &$returnData=null){
    if(!$fns){
        return;
    }
    if(is_array($fns)){
        foreach($fns as $f){
            $f($cdata, $returnData);
        }
    }else{
        $fns($cdata, $returnData);
    }
}

$response = null;
if(is_array($data)){
    $response = array();
    foreach($data as $d){
        $response[] = doRpc($d);
    }
}else{
    $response = doRpc($data);
}
if($isForm && $isUpload){
    echo '<html><body><textarea>';
    echo json_encode($response);
    echo '</textarea></body></html>';
}else{
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

QueryDatabase.php (sql request php file)

```
<?php

 class QueryDatabase {

    private $_db;
    protected $_result;
    public $results;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_db = new mysqli(MY CREDENTIALS);

        $_db = $this->_db;

        if ($_db->connect_error) {
            die('Connection Error: ' . $_db->connect_error);
        }

        return $_db;
    }

    public function getResults($params) {
        $_db = $this->_db;

        $_result = $_db->query("SELECT name,email,phone FROM heroes") or
                   die('Connection Error: ' . $_db->connect_error);

        $results = array();

        while ($row = $_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($results, $row);
        }

        $this->_db->close();

        return $results;
    }
 }
```

and finally config.php file

```
<?php

function get_extdirect_api() {
    $API = array(
        'QueryDatabase' => array(
            'methods' => array(
                'getResults' => array(
                    'len' => 1
                )
            )
        )
    );

    return $API;
}
```

edit2

here is full network tab from firefox screenshots

edit 3
here is api.php details from network tab

[answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uRkS.png)

[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR5Rh.png)

[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWb5X.png)

here is the configuration file sencha.cfg which is configuration of the minimal web server provided my sencha CMD

```
# sencha.cfg
#
# This is the main configuration file for Sencha Cmd. The properties defined in
# this file are used to initialize Sencha Cmd and should be edited with some
# caution.
#
# On previous versions, this file provided a way to specify the cmd.jvm.* properties
# to control the execution of the JVM. To accommodate all possible execution scenarios
# support for these properties has been removed in favor of using the _JAVA_OPTIONS
# environment variable.
#

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This indicates the platform that Cmd is installed on.  This is used for
# platform specific package management.
#
# Possible values: windows, osx, linux, linux-x64
#
# cmd.platform=

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This is the Sencha Cmd version.
#
# THIS PROPERTY SHOULD NOT BE MODIFIED.

cmd.version=6.5.3.6

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This indicates the level of backwards compatibility provided. That is to say,
# apps requiring versions between cmd.minver and cmd.version (inclusive) should
# be able to use this version.
#
# THIS PROPERTY SHOULD NOT BE MODIFIED.

cmd.minver=3.0.0.0

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The folder for the local package repository. By default, this folder is shared
# by all versions of Sencha Cmd. In other words, upgrading Sencha Cmd does not
# affect the local repository.

repo.local.dir=${cmd.dir}/../repo

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This is the default port to use for the Sencha Cmd Web Server.

cmd.web.port=1841

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Java System Properties
#
# By setting any "system.*" properties you can set Java System Properties. For
# general information on these, see:
#
# http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html
#

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Proxy Settings
#
# The primary reason to set Java System Properties is to handle HTTP Proxies.
# By default, Java uses "http.proxy*" properties to configure HTTP proxies, but
# the "java.net.useSystemProxies" option can be enabled to improve the use of
# system-configured proxy settings based on your platform. If this setting does
# not work for your proxy server setup, try disabling this setting by commenting
# it out and enabling the other settings. See also this information on proxy
# setup:
#
# http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html
#
# NOTE: If you find that you need to adjust these settings, you may want to do
# so in a "sencha.cfg" file one folder above this folder. The settings in that
# file override these settings, so be sure to only copy the settings you need
# to that location. The advantage to putting these settings in that location is
# that they will not be "lost" as you upgrade Cmd.

system.java.net.useSystemProxies=true

# These are the legacy options that come in to play when the above is commented
# out:
#system.http.proxyHost=proxy.mycompany.com
#system.http.proxyPort=80
#system.http.proxyUser=username
#system.http.proxyPassword=password

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Merge Tool Settings
#
# To enable use of a visual merge tool to resolve merge conflicts, set the
# following property to the desired merge tool path:
#
#       cmd.merge.tool=p4merge
#
# Next, to configure the arguments for the merge tool, set this property:
#
#       cmd.merge.tool.args={base} {user} {generated} {out}
#
# Alternatively, the arguments for several merge tools are defined below and can
# be used in your configuration for simplicity/clarity like so:
#
#       cmd.merge.tool.args=${cmd.merge.tool.args.sourcegear}
#
# NOTE: the cmd.merge.tool.args property is split on spaces *then* the tokens
# are replaced by actual files names. This avoids the need to quote arguments to
# handle spaces in paths.
#
# NOTE: Some merge tools (like SmartSynchronize) do not accept the output file
# separately so there is no way to know if the merge was completed. In this case,
# the base file is where the result is written so Cmd just copies the content of
# that file back as the result.
#
# You can add the appropriate lines to customize your Cmd configuration. See
# below for details.

# The arguments for p4merge, see below for download:
# http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-merge-and-diff-tools
cmd.merge.tool.args.p4merge={base} {user} {generated} {out}

# SourceGear (http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/index.html)
cmd.merge.tool.args.sourcegear=--merge --result={out} {user} {base} {generated}

# kdiff3 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/kdiff3/files/kdiff3/)
cmd.merge.tool.args.kdiff3={base} {user} {generated} -o {out}

# Syntevo SmartSynchronize 3 (http://www.syntevo.com/smartsynchronize/index.html).
cmd.merge.tool.args.smartsync={user} {generated} {base}

# TortoiseMerge (part of TortoiseSVN - see http://tortoisesvn.net).
cmd.merge.tool.args.tortoise=-base:{base} -theirs:{generated} -mine:{user} -merged:{out}

# AraxisMerge (see http://www.araxis.com/merge-overview.html):
cmd.merge.tool.args.araxis=-wait -merge -3 -a1 {base} {user} {generated} {out}

# The address where Sencha Inspector is located
inspector.address=http://localhost:1839/

# this variable references a json file containing unicode code points to be
# printed in escaped form during code generation.
cmd.unicode.escapes=${cmd.dir}/unicode-escapes.json

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Customizing Configuration
#
# Customization can be handled any of these ways:
#
#   1. Place customizations in this file (ideally at the bottom) and they will
#      configure this instance of Sencha Cmd.
#
#   2. Create a "sencha.cfg" file in the folder above this instance of Sencha Cmd
#      to be shared by all installed versions.
#
#   3. Create a "~/.sencha/cmd/sencha.cfg" file. On Windows, the "~" maps to your
#      %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% folder (e.g., "C:\Users\Me").
#
# Your personal settings take priority over common settings (item #2) which both
# take priority of instance settings (this file).
```

thank you

Comment: The answer is the same as in the other question: Without you showing us your PHP code and what the Network Tab of your browser returns when you call said PHP script, we cannot help you.

Comment: @Alexander done

Comment: Please also show what the network tab of the browser returns from the call to api.php (screenshot).

Comment: @Alexander done

Comment: What I wanted you to show to us is the data that is returned from the call to the PHP file, like in [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/iT9IzW5.png). Seems you don't really know what you're doing. You should start with basic PHP debugging and basic ExtJS debugging before mixing the two together.

Comment: @Alexander sorry was doing something else at the same time and didn't read well your message. Here is php.api GET request (the only api.php request) headers, answer and stack trace

Comment: PHP is executed server-side, its code should never hit the browser. Your web server obviously does not execute PHP.

You may want to edit your question, remove all refences to ExtJS or your PHP code and instead show us the web server setup you have.

Comment: You have to get PHP working in such a way that a PHP script containing just the line `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, when called from the browser, shows a page just like the one you get when [opening this page and clicking "Run"](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%20phpinfo()?%3E).

Comment: when using sencha cmd (that's what i do) you have a minimal web server running for your app.

Comment: The point there is "minimal", it does not support PHP. You have to install and use a different web server with PHP support.

Comment: @Alexander you sure about that ? in sencha docs it's never said that it doesn't support php and it's said nowhere in requirements. Then i will try thank you for your help if you have more details to help me you can tell me

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are also following the guide and using the sencha app watch and getting the php code returning back to you. I found this answer on a Sencha forum that the web server that the sencha cmd provides doesn't support php is just a basic HTTP web server.

Comment: Found what answer?

Comment: so sorry I forgot to put the link there and somehow can-t find it anymore but the answer is just that the webserver from the cmd will just return the code and not process it and that-s why it returns the php code.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the exact same thing today and came across the post....

For anyone else looking for the problem this is how i fixed it.  Basically you have to get the posted data in a slightly different manner... looks at the first comment in the code below

```
<?php
 require('config.php');

 class BogusAction {
    public $action;
    public $method;
    public $data;
    public $tid;
 }

 $isForm = false;
 $isUpload = false;
  
 // different way to get the data that is posted to the URL 
 $postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
 
 if (isset($postData)) {
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
    $data = json_decode($postData);
 }
 else if (isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
    $data = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
 }
 else if(isset($_POST['extAction'])){ // form post
    $isForm = true;
    $isUpload = $_POST['extUpload'] == 'true';
    $data = new BogusAction();
    $data->action = $_POST['extAction'];
    $data->method = $_POST['extMethod'];
    $data->tid = isset($_POST['extTID']) ? $_POST['extTID'] : null;
    $data->data = array($_POST, $_FILES);
 }
 else {
    die('Invalid request min .');
 }

 function doRpc($cdata){
    $API = get_extdirect_api('router');
    
    try {
        if (!isset($API[$cdata->action])) {
            throw new Exception('Call to undefined action: ' . $cdata->action);
        }

        $action = $cdata->action;
        $a = $API[$action];

        $method = $cdata->method;
        $mdef = $a['methods'][$method];

        if (!$mdef){
            throw new Exception("Call to undefined method: $method " .
                                "in action $action");
        }

        $r = array(
            'type'=>'rpc',
            'tid'=>$cdata->tid,
            'action'=>$action,
            'method'=>$method
        );

        require_once("classes/$action.php");
        $o = new $action();

        if (isset($mdef['len'])) {
            $params = isset($cdata->data) && is_array($cdata->data) ? $cdata->data : array();
        }
        else {
            $params = array($cdata->data);
        }

        $r['result'] = call_user_func_array(array($o, $method), $params);
    }

    catch(Exception $e){
        $r['type'] = 'exception';
        $r['message'] = $e->getMessage();
        $r['where'] = $e->getTraceAsString();
    }

    return $r;
 }

 $response = null;

 if (is_array($data)) {
    $response = array();
    foreach($data as $d){
        $response[] = doRpc($d);
    }
 }
 else{
    $response = doRpc($data);
 }

 if ($isForm && $isUpload){
    echo '<html><body><textarea>';
    echo json_encode($response);
    echo '</textarea></body></html>';
 }
 else{
    echo json_encode($response);
 }
 ?>
```